# clang-format file not working in Visual Studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, clang-format

I have put a `.clang-format` file in my workspace. But that formatting is not applied on my code. I have checked the settings and they are set to None for fallback-style and file for `clang_format_style`.

The good news is that the fallback Style doesn't work anymore. Which means when I try to Format the Document or Selection nothing happens.

This is what I did to make my custom formatting:

[visualstudio.com: Edit C++ in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/cpp-ide)

But there is something missing and the formatting is no happening. This is what my `.clang-format` in my workspace looks like:

```
{ 
UseTab: 14, 
IndentWidth: 4,
 BreakBeforeBraces: BS_Attach,
 AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: false,
 IndentCaseLabels: false,
 ColumnLimit: 0 
}
```

Comment: I am a bit surprised about the silence here. Where can I raise the question if not here

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've just suffered from this issue, but it appears to be a minor bug in VS Code.  In my settings I had `Editor: Format On Save` turned on, `C_Cpp: Clang_format_style` set to `file`, and `C_Cpp: Formatting` set to `Default` (which is stated as clang-format).  But nothing happened on save.

To 'fix' it, I forcibly triggered a format by selecting some code and clicking `Format Selection` which then gave me a dialog whining about there being multiple formatters available and that I have to pick one from the command palette.  It looks like the builtin MS Intellisense one and clang-format were fighting for dominance - despite the fact that clang-format was listed as default in the settings!  After selecting clang-format here, it was all fine again.

Answer (score 1):

Just for documentation if anybody else comes through this issue, I have suffered this issue but due to a different cause. I added a newer option to my .clang-format file that was not supported by the version of clang-format I have installed on my system. It ends up it was failing silently and the symptom was that the file was not being formatted.

So make sure you know which clang-format you are using, the full path, and use that to format one of your files manually, to see if there is any error message being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR - If the encoding of .clang-format is UTF-16, convert or generate in UTF-8 to solve issue.

I hope this might be helpful for some people.

I usually generate my .clang-format file by using the formatter to dump a styled configuration for me, then I edit the options I need. ie. `clang-format.exe --style=Microsoft --dump-config > .clang-format`

When trying to format, I kept on getting the Formatting failed - see output window. The output window didn't show anything useful. Entering this on the command line just seemed to want to take input from stdin.

It turns out that the Windows version of clang-format.exe when dumping a configuration is redirected to a file, Windows will dutifully save it in UTF-16.

There is probably some setting somewhere in windows to save in UTF-8 but I fixed this by generating the file using a Linux version of clang-format and then copying to where I needed it in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the following options in Formatting

Format on Paste

Format on Save

Format on Save Mode: file

have to be checked. Now it works fine. Also look into the settings.json file made by the App. Double check your settings and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

OMG! This is so frustrating. But at the cost of one Saturday morning, I'm confident I understand the root cause (as hinted by Henrique Bucher in another answer here, thank you Henrique!).

The way VS Code invokes clang-format has a "graceful" failover: if your .clang-format contains unrecognized settings, then it falls back to an *entirely different* configuration. But it does this SILENTLY!

So what happens:

1. Your project has a perfectly functional .clang-format and you are happily coding along.
2. You add something new to .clang-format that is actually invalid (perhaps because it was hallucinated by Github Copilot).
3. As a result, clang-format now silently fails with your custom file and instead falls back to a completely different configuration (probably `BasedOnStyle: Visual Studio` or something). But there is no indication this is happening.
4. Depending on how close your settings are to the fallback, you might not notice this at the time especially if you are only changing/formatting a very small number of lines.
5. Then when you try to make another change or debug why your formatting suddenly doesn't work, you waste hours of your life.
6. This is trivial to repro, just open .clang-format and add some gibberish "asdf" to the top of the file and then (in VS Code) `format` various chunks of code, the formatting with change drastically.

Note that via command line invocation, clang-format does NOT work this way. It fails immediately and verbosely.

So if you are trying to debug why your .clang-format apparently does not apply in VS Code (especially if it did previously), be sure to hop into the Terminal and try a manual invocation.

Copilot giveth, and Copilot taketh away :-(